# JQuery Autocomplete Error: Cannot find property 'hide' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Autocomplete won't work on my ASP.NET project.

Scenario is that an input textbox is added to a form that will have an autocomplete feature. Checked the appended input textbox and the code actually gets it. Used dummy options for the meantime as well but still won't work.

Here's the code:

```
self.valueContainer.append('<input type="text" name="InputValues" id="selectedOptionListItemSearchText" />');``

var searchText = jQuery('#selectedOptionListItemSearchText');

searchText .autocomplete({
    delay: 300,
    minLength: 1,
    source: ["test","option"]
});
```

And the error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

That stops at this part of the jquery-ui-1.12.0.js :

```
this._initSource();
this.menu = $( "<ul>" )
    .appendTo( this._appendTo() )
    .menu( {
        // disable ARIA support, the live region takes care of that
        role: null
    } )
    .hide()
    .menu( "instance" );
```

Any feedback and help appreciated!

Regards

Comment: sounds like menu() is not returning anything...

Comment: Try $( "ul" ) instead of $( "<ul>" )

Comment: @Emeeus Tried it but still the same error.

Comment: @epascarello Tried tracing it but as it is within the jQuery file itself, I find it hard to fully understand. All I understand is that it is having a problem with creating the selection list even if I provided already.